# Subspace of $L(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $E$ is a subspace of $L(V)$ such that $ST\in E$ and $TS \in E$ for all $S \in L(V)$ and $T\in E$. Prove that $E=\{0\}$ or $E =L(V)$.

When $E$ is non-trivial, I want to prove that $1 \in E$. Then we can deduce that $L(V) \subset E$ and we are done. However, I don't know how to use the fact '$ST\in E$ and $TS \in E$'.

To me, $L(V)$ is a ring and clearly $E$ is an ideal of ring. Still, why $1 \in E?$

Comment: What is $L(V)$? The set of linear maps on $V$?

Comment: @Cameron Williams yes

Comment: What do you define $TS$ as?

Comment: @GPerez I would assume as function composition.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Disregard, I got confused because I thought $T$ was an element of $V$.

Comment: Obviously we need to use the fact that $E$ is a subspace, since the statement for any left and right ideal is false. The only thing that I could think of was using the annihilating polynomial of each $T\in E$. If one of the terms is $1$, we could conclude. However $1$ doesn't necessarily have to appear in the annihilating polynomial. We could then factor out a power of $E$, but since neither of the two factors have to be zero, I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @GPerez What do you mean the statement for left and right ideals is false?

Comment: @anon That came out strangely. I meant that we should take advantage of the finite dimensional vector space structure, since in general the condition of $I$ being a left and right ideal of a ring $A$ does not imply that it has to be either $\{0\}$ or $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis for $V$. Let $0\neq T\in E$. So exists $ v\in V$ such that $T(v)\neq 0$.

Let $R_i\in L(V)$ be such that $R_i(v_i)=v$ and $R_{i}(v_j)=0$, for $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$.

Let $S_i\in L(V)$ be such that $S_i(T(v))=v_i$, for $1\leq i\leq n$.

Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^nS_iTR_i(v_j)=S_jTR_j(v_j)=S_jT(v)=v_j$ for $1\leq j\leq n$. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^nS_iTR_i=Id$ and since $S_iTR_i\in E$, we obtain $Id\in E$.

If $S\in L(V)$ then $Id.S=S\in E$.